# Re-Write jQuery Function To Handle Two Multi-Level Drop-Down Menus On The Same Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing a settings page with two multi-level drop-down menus. The first menu is the site main, which sits at the top of the page, and the second menu is lower down the page and used for navigating settings features such as change avatar, timezone, email address, etc.

If there were only one menu on the page there would be no problem. I wish to use the same menu for settings to keep the page appearance uniform. The problem I'm running into is having them behave separately. Opening one, opens the other and there's a duplication of the mobile menu for both.

At first, I thought I could simply switch the `.find()` command in the jQuery function to `.closest()`, then I tried `.next()`, neither of them worked. I duplicated the function and changed all variables to make it a separate function, but that caused the lower menu to stop working entirely.

I tried given each menu separate IDs and within the `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` tried to initialize them separately, but that hasn't worked either.

An online search discovered all kinds of examples of other menu types, but nowhere could I find anything to help me resolve this issue. It's simply beyond my level of experience.

The code below runs both menus as one. It has been my starting point for the past two days.

https://jsfiddle.net/Assorro/vwrzhxsa/

HTML

```
<div class="stellarnav" id="stellar1">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="stellarnav" id="stellar2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('.stellarnav').stellarNav({
      theme: 'dark',
      breakpoint: 960
    });
  });

</script>
```

CSS

```
.stellarnav {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9900;
  line-height: normal;
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.stellarnav a {
  color: #777;
}

.stellarnav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.stellarnav li {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  line-height: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.stellarnav li a {
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #777;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

/* main level */

.stellarnav>ul>li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.stellarnav>ul>li>a {
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

/* first level dd */

.stellarnav ul ul {
  top: auto;
  width: 220px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9900;
  text-align: left;
  display: none;
  background: #ddd;
}

.stellarnav li li {
  display: block;
}

/* second level dd */

.stellarnav ul ul ul {
  top: 0;
  /* dd animtion - change to auto to remove */
  left: 220px;
}

.stellarnav>ul>li:hover>ul>li:hover>ul {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0;
}

/* .drop-left */

.stellarnav>ul>li.drop-left>ul {
  right: 0;
}

.stellarnav li.drop-left ul ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 220px;
}

/* light theme */

.stellarnav.light {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.stellarnav.light a {
  color: #000;
}

.stellarnav.light ul ul {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.stellarnav.light li a {
  color: #000;
}

/* dark theme */

.stellarnav.dark {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0px 15px rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.35);
}

.stellarnav.dark a {
  color: #538fbe;
}

.stellarnav.dark ul ul {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
}

.stellarnav.dark li a {
  color: #5b8daf;
}

.stellarnav.dark li a:hover {
  color: #5b8daf;
  background: rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.1);
}

/* sticky nav */

.stellarnav.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}

/* only used when 'scrollbarFix' is set to true in the js. This fixes horizontal scrollbar caused by the dd menus that are very long.*/

body.stellarnav-noscroll-x {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

/* general styling */

.stellarnav li.has-sub>a:after {
  content: '';
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid #5b8daf;
  display: inline-block;
}

.stellarnav li li.has-sub>a:after {
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: right;
  border-top: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
  border-left: 6px solid #5b8daf;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
}

.stellarnav li.drop-left li.has-sub>a:after {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 6px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid #5b8daf;
}

.stellarnav.hide-arrows li.has-sub>a:after,
.stellarnav.hide-arrows li li.has-sub>a:after,
.stellarnav.hide-arrows li.drop-left li.has-sub>a:after {
  display: none;
}

.stellarnav .menu-toggle,
.stellarnav .close-menu,
.stellarnav .call-btn-mobile,
.stellarnav .location-btn-mobile {
  display: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.stellarnav .dd-toggle {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 0;
}

.stellarnav.desktop li.has-sub a {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.stellarnav.desktop.hide-arrows li.has-sub a {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.stellarnav.mobile>ul>li>a.dd-toggle {
  padding: 0;
}

.stellarnav li.call-btn-mobile,
.stellarnav li.location-btn-mobile {
  display: none;
}

/* svg icons */

.stellarnav svg {
  fill: currentColor;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}

/* svg icons */

.stellarnav a.dd-toggle .icon-plus {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  width: 12px;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.stellarnav a.dd-toggle .icon-plus:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 0px;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #777;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: width 0.3s;
}

.stellarnav a.dd-toggle .icon-plus:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #777;
  position: absolute;
}

.stellarnav li.open>a.dd-toggle .icon-plus {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}

.stellarnav.light a.dd-toggle .icon-plus:before {
  border-color: #000;
}

.stellarnav.light a.dd-toggle .icon-plus:after {
  border-color: #000;
}

.stellarnav.dark a.dd-toggle .icon-plus:before {
  border-color: #FFF;
}

.stellarnav.dark a.dd-toggle .icon-plus:after {
  border-color: #FFF;
}

.stellarnav .icon-close {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.stellarnav .icon-close:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 0px;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #777;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.stellarnav .icon-close:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  border-bottom: solid 3px #777;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.stellarnav.light .icon-close:before {
  border-color: #000;
}

.stellarnav.light .icon-close:after {
  border-color: #000;
}

.stellarnav.dark .icon-close:before {
  border-color: #FFF;
}

.stellarnav.dark .icon-close:after {
  border-color: #FFF;
}

/* mobile nav */

.stellarnav .menu-toggle,
.stellarnav .call-btn-mobile,
.stellarnav .location-btn-mobile,
.stellarnav .close-menu {
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.stellarnav .menu-toggle span.bars {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 7px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}

.stellarnav .menu-toggle span.bars span {
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: #777;
  margin: 0 0 3px;
}

.stellarnav .full {
  width: 100%;
}

.stellarnav .half {
  width: 50%;
}

.stellarnav .third {
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
}

.stellarnav .location-btn-mobile.third {
  text-align: center;
}

.stellarnav .location-btn-mobile.half {
  text-align: right;
}

.stellarnav.light .third,
.stellarnav.light .half {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.stellarnav.light.left .third,
.stellarnav.light.left .half {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.stellarnav.light.right .third,
.stellarnav.light.right .half {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.stellarnav.light .third:first-child,
.stellarnav.light .half:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}

.stellarnav.dark .third,
.stellarnav.dark .half {
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}

.stellarnav.dark.left .third,
.stellarnav.dark.left .half {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}

.stellarnav.dark.right .third,
.stellarnav.dark.right .half {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}

.stellarnav.light.left .menu-toggle,
.stellarnav.light.right .menu-toggle {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.stellarnav.dark.left .menu-toggle,
.stellarnav.dark.right .menu-toggle {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.stellarnav.dark .third:first-child,
.stellarnav.dark .half:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}

.stellarnav.light .menu-toggle span.bars span {
  background: #000;
}

.stellarnav.dark .menu-toggle span.bars span {
  background: #538fbe;
}

.stellarnav.mobile {
  position: static;
}

.stellarnav.mobile.fixed {
  position: static;
}

.stellarnav.mobile ul {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

.stellarnav.mobile.active {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.stellarnav.mobile.active>ul {
  display: block;
}

.stellarnav.mobile ul {
  text-align: left;
}

.stellarnav.mobile>ul>li {
  display: block;
}

.stellarnav.mobile>ul>li>a {
  padding: 15px;
}

.stellarnav.mobile ul {
  background: rgba(221, 221, 221, 1);
}

.stellarnav.mobile ul ul {
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  width: auto;
  display: none;
  -moz-transition: none;
  -webkit-transition: none;
  -o-transition: color 0 ease-in;
  transition: none;
}

.stellarnav.mobile ul ul ul {
  left: auto;
  top: auto;
}

.stellarnav.mobile li.drop-left ul ul {
  right: auto;
}

.stellarnav.mobile li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}

.stellarnav.mobile>ul {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .15);
}

.stellarnav.mobile.light li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.stellarnav.mobile.light>ul {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.stellarnav.mobile li a.dd-toggle {
  border: 0;
}

.stellarnav.mobile.light li a.dd-toggle {
  border: 0;
}

.stellarnav.mobile .menu-toggle,
.stellarnav.mobile .dd-toggle,
.stellarnav.mobile .close-menu,
.stellarnav.mobile .call-btn-mobile,
.stellarnav.mobile .location-btn-mobile {
  display: inline-block;
}

.stellarnav.mobile li.call-btn-mobile {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.stellarnav.mobile li.call-btn-mobile,
.stellarnav.mobile li.location-btn-mobile {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.stellarnav.mobile li.call-btn-mobile.full,
.stellarnav.mobile li.location-btn-mobile.full {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-right: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.stellarnav.mobile.light ul {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.stellarnav.mobile.dark ul {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.stellarnav.mobile.dark ul ul {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .08);
}

.stellarnav.mobile.light li.call-btn-mobile {
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.stellarnav.mobile.top {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.stellarnav.mobile li.has-sub>a:after,
.stellarnav.mobile li li.has-sub>a:after,
.stellarnav.mobile li.drop-left li.has-sub>a:after {
  display: none;
}

/* left and right positions */

.stellarnav.mobile.right>ul,
.stellarnav.mobile.left>ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 280px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.stellarnav.mobile.right>ul {
  right: 0;
}

.stellarnav.mobile.right .close-menu,
.stellarnav.mobile.left .close-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}

.stellarnav.mobile.left>ul {
  left: 0;
}

.stellarnav.mobile.right .location-btn-mobile.half,
.stellarnav.mobile.right .call-btn-mobile.half,
.stellarnav.mobile.right .close-menu.half {
  text-align: center;
}

.stellarnav.mobile.right .location-btn-mobile.third,
.stellarnav.mobile.right .call-btn-mobile.third,
.stellarnav.mobile.right .close-menu.third {
  text-align: center;
}

.stellarnav.mobile.left .location-btn-mobile.half,
.stellarnav.mobile.left .call-btn-mobile.half,
.stellarnav.mobile.left .close-menu.half {
  text-align: center;
}

.stellarnav.mobile.left .location-btn-mobile.third,
.stellarnav.mobile.left .call-btn-mobile.third,
.stellarnav.mobile.left .close-menu.third {
  text-align: center;
}

.stellarnav.mobile.left .menu-toggle.half,
.stellarnav.mobile.left .menu-toggle.third,
.stellarnav.mobile.right .menu-toggle.half,
.stellarnav.mobile.right .menu-toggle.third {
  text-align: left;
}

.stellarnav.mobile.left .close-menu.third span,
.stellarnav.mobile.right .close-menu.third span {
  display: none;
}

/* left and right positions */

/* mega dd */

.stellarnav.desktop li.mega ul ul {
  background: none;
}

.stellarnav.desktop li.mega li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: -4px;
}

.stellarnav.desktop li.mega li li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 4px;
}

.stellarnav.desktop li.mega ul ul {
  width: auto;
}

.stellarnav.desktop>ul>li.mega {
  position: inherit;
}

.stellarnav.desktop>ul>li.mega>ul {
  width: 100%;
}

.stellarnav.desktop>ul>li.mega>ul li.has-sub ul {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: auto;
}

.stellarnav.desktop>ul>li.mega>ul>li {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.stellarnav.desktop li.mega li li a {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

.stellarnav.desktop li.mega li.has-sub a:after {
  display: none;
}

.stellarnav.desktop>ul>li.mega>ul>li>a {
  color: yellow;
}

/* mega dd */

/* Fallback for slow javascript load */

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .stellarnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
  }
  .stellarnav ul {
    position: relative;
    display: none;
  }
  .patrons {
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
  }
  #separate_topic_container {
    position: relative;
    top: 60px;
  }
}

/* mobile nav */

@media only screen and (max-width: 420px) {
  .stellarnav.mobile .call-btn-mobile.third span,
  .stellarnav.mobile .location-btn-mobile.third span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

jQuery

```
! function(u) {
  u.fn.stellarNav = function(n, r, h) {
    nav = u(this), r = u(window).width();
    var f = u.extend({
      theme: "plain",
      breakpoint: 768,
      menuLabel: "Menu",
      sticky: !1,
      position: "static",
      openingSpeed: 250,
      closingDelay: 250,
      showArrows: !0,
      phoneBtn: "",
      phoneLabel: "Call Us",
      locationBtn: "",
      locationLabel: "Location",
      closeBtn: !1,
      closeLabel: "Close",
      mobileMode: !1,
      scrollbarFix: !1
    }, n);
    return this.each(function() {
      if ("light" != f.theme && "dark" != f.theme || nav.addClass(f.theme), f.breakpoint && (h = f.breakpoint), f.menuLabel ? menuLabel = f.menuLabel : menuLabel = "", f.phoneLabel ? phoneLabel = f.phoneLabel : phoneLabel = "", f.locationLabel ? locationLabel = f.locationLabel : locationLabel = "", f.closeLabel ? closeLabel = f.closeLabel : closeLabel = "", f.phoneBtn && f.locationBtn) var n = "third";
      else if (f.phoneBtn || f.locationBtn) n = "half";
      else n = "full";
      if ("right" == f.position || "left" == f.position ? nav.prepend() : nav.prepend('<a href="#" class="menu-toggle ' + n + '"><span class="bars"><span></span><span></span><span></span></span> ' + menuLabel + "</a>")) {}
      u(".menu-toggle, .stellarnav-open").on("click", function(n) {
        n.preventDefault(), "left" == f.position || "right" == f.position ? (nav.find("ul:first").stop(!0, !0).fadeToggle(f.openingSpeed), nav.toggleClass("active"), nav.hasClass("active") && nav.hasClass("mobile") && u(document).on("click", function(n) {
          nav.hasClass("mobile") && (u(n.target).closest(nav).length || (nav.find("ul:first").stop(!0, !0).fadeOut(f.openingSpeed), nav.removeClass("active")))
        })) : (nav.find("ul:first").stop(!0, !0).slideToggle(f.openingSpeed), nav.toggleClass("active"))
      }), u(".close-menu, .stellarnav-close").on("click", function() {
        nav.removeClass("active"), "left" == f.position || "right" == f.position ? nav.find("ul:first").stop(!0, !0).fadeToggle(f.openingSpeed) : nav.find("ul:first").stop(!0, !0).slideUp(f.openingSpeed).toggleClass("active")
      }), nav.find("li a").each(function() {
        0 < u(this).next().length && u(this).parent("li").addClass("has-sub").append('<a class="dd-toggle" href="#"><span class="icon-plus"></span></a>')
      }), nav.find("li .dd-toggle").on("click", function(n) {
        n.preventDefault(), u(this).parent("li").children("ul").stop(!0, !0).slideToggle(f.openingSpeed), u(this).parent("li").toggleClass("open")
      });
      var c = function() {
        nav.find("li").off("mouseenter"), nav.find("li").off("mouseleave")
      };
      parentItems = nav.find("> ul > li");

      function p() {
        window.innerWidth <= h || f.mobileMode ? (c(), nav.addClass("mobile"), nav.removeClass("desktop"), !nav.hasClass("active") && nav.find("ul:first").is(":visible") && nav.find("ul:first").hide(), nav.find("li.mega").each(function() {
          u(this).find("ul").first().removeAttr("style"), u(this).find("ul").first().children().removeAttr("style")
        })) : (nav.addClass("desktop"), nav.removeClass("mobile"), nav.hasClass("active") && nav.removeClass("active"), !nav.hasClass("active") && nav.find("ul:first").is(":hidden") && nav.find("ul:first").show(), u("li.open").removeClass("open").find("ul:visible").hide(), c(), u(parentItems).each(function() {
          u(this).hasClass("mega") ? (u(this).on("mouseenter", function() {
            u(this).find("ul").first().stop(!0, !0).slideDown(f.openingSpeed)
          }), u(this).on("mouseleave", function() {
            u(this).find("ul").first().stop(!0, !0).slideUp(f.openingSpeed)
          })) : (u(this).on("mouseenter", function() {
            u(this).children("ul").stop(!0, !0).slideDown(f.openingSpeed)
          }), u(this).on("mouseleave", function() {
            u(this).children("ul").stop(!0, !0).delay(f.closingDelay).slideUp(f.openingSpeed)
          }), u(this).find("li.has-sub").on("mouseenter", function() {
            u(this).children("ul").stop(!0, !0).slideDown(f.openingSpeed)
          }), u(this).find("li.has-sub").on("mouseleave", function() {
            u(this).children("ul").stop(!0, !0).delay(f.closingDelay).slideUp(f.openingSpeed)
          }))
        }), navWidth = 0, u(parentItems).each(function() {
          navWidth += u(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().width, navWidth = Math.round(navWidth), u(this).hasClass("mega") && (u(this).find("ul").first().css({
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            margin: "0px auto"
          }), numCols = u(this).attr("data-columns"), 2 == numCols ? u(this).find("li.has-sub").width("50%") : 3 == numCols ? u(this).find("ul").first().children().width("33.33%") : 4 == numCols ? u(this).find("ul").first().children().width("25%") : 5 == numCols ? u(this).find("ul").first().children().width("20%") : 6 == numCols ? u(this).find("ul").first().children().width("16.66%") : 7 == numCols ? u(this).find("ul").first().children().width("14.28%") : 8 == numCols ? u(this).find("ul").first().children().width("12.5%") : u(this).find("ul").first().children().width("25%"))
        }), parentItems.hasClass("mega") && nav.find("li.mega > ul").css({
          "max-width": navWidth
        }))
      }
      p(), u(window).on("resize", function() {
        p()
      })
    })
  }
}(jQuery);
```

I expect the function to treat each menu separately so that each reacts independently of the other.

Comment: Where is that jQuery code coming from? Looks like a "uglified" and minified version of some source code. Maybe it has been through some JS bundler?

Comment: It's the function included with Stellar Menu in stellarnav.min.js

Comment: I'd say the issue is coming from StellarNav itself, and I suggest to open an issue in the main [GitHub repository](https://github.com/vinnymoreira/stellarnav).

Comment: I have opened an issue in the main GitHub repository here. https://github.com/vinnymoreira/stellarnav/issues/20  This issue being resolved would benefit not just me, but others looking to resolve similar obstacles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue of having the two separate menus behave separately on the same page, I was unable to accomplish this by using the one function alone. I needed to duplicate the function and change all the variable names by simply adding a "2" to each variable within the second function. Initializing them separately using the same function caused the top menu to stop working as the function was then assigning itself to the lower menu only.

It's a responsive menu, and while in mobile mode each mobile menu button would operate the second menu only. The button within the second menu function needed its ID changed. So class=".menu-toggle" became class=".menu-toggle2". The CSS also needed to be modified to include .menu-toggle2.

The initializing needed to be separate but it now works. It's a rare instance to need two identical responsive menus on the same page, but when you do, this solution will do the trick.

Final Markup

```
<div class="stellarnav" id="stellar1" style="z-index:10000;">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="stellarnav" id="stellar2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" onclick="return false;">Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initializeStellarNav(index, element) {
    $(element).stellarNav({
      theme: 'dark',
      breakpoint: 960
    });
  }
  function initializeStellarNav2(index, element) {
    $(element).stellarNav2({
      theme2: 'dark',
      breakpoint2: 960
    });
  }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    initializeStellarNav(1, '#stellar1');
    initializeStellarNav2(2, '#stellar2');
  });
</script>
```

Working Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Assorro/oeLwvf4m/

GitHub Issue

https://github.com/vinnymoreira/stellarnav/issues/20

Original Source

https://github.com/vinnymoreira/stellarnav

Answer (score 0):

Uglified code seems to reference both nav elements under single variable `var nav = u(this);`

Can you perhaps try invoking `stellarNav` per element? Like so:

```
function initializeStellarNav(index, element) {
    $(element).stellarNav({
        theme: 'dark',
        breakpoint: 960
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $navs = jQuery('.stellarnav');
    $navs.each(initializeStellarNav);
});
```

Comment: That is remarkably close to the desired effect. It looks like the second menu is cancelling the first menu. I modified the fiddle to show what's happening now. I also gave each menu their own distinct ID and have edited my question above to reflect that change. https://jsfiddle.net/Assorro/anm5qu4h/